# Connecting FluidEnter/FluidExit at run-time

Tags: anylogic

I am toying with the FluidEnter/FluidExit. So in a simple form, here is what I am trying to do:

I created in Main an empty population of agent called Terminal. For now, in Terminal, there is only a fluidEnter connected to a fluidExit (very simple)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZb5f.png)

Now, on startup, I want to fill this population and set up the proper connections (the terminals are ordered).

So, on startup, I call a function init(), whose body start with Terminal t = add_terminals(); (I have only one terminal for now, just toying with things)

In Main, obviously, I also have a fluidEnter and a fluidExit. I would like to connect the fluidExit of Main to the fluidEnter of the terminal t, and the fluidExit of the terminal t to the fluidEnter  of Main, so code (still in init()) looks like

fluidExit.set_fluidEnter(t.fluidEnter);
t.fluidExit.set_fluidEnter(fluidEnter);

I get an exception so obviously, I am doing something wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think the set_fluidEnter function is deprecated or just non-functional.

Instead, you should do:

```
fluidExit.connect(t.fluidEnter);
```

So just replace set_fluidEnter with connect... nothing else.

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I was going down the same path as you a couple of months ago.  Yes... `.connect()` works great.  It even works as a gate.  If it is disconnected, then fluid stops at the exit.  Once connected, fluid starts to flow again.  It is very slick.

Comment: Yes, connect() is the way to go. Thanks